# Accessing Spring FormatterRegistry from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application that uses a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` instead of a `WebMvcConfigurer`.

I need to add a custom Spring converter to the `FormatterRegistry` provided by Spring, but that only appears to be a property of `WebMvcConfigurer`, *not* `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

How can my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` access the Spring provided `FormatterRegistry`?

Comment: You cannot as both beans are for a different purpose.

Comment: Ahh but I can, please see below!

Comment: Although that might work that is not the way it is intended :). Just implement `WebMvcConfigurer` so that it will be configured at the right time.

Comment: Like Thanos, reality can be whatever I want.

Comment: Not really. As the `WebMvcConfigurer` is configured as part of the MVC setup. Whereas your solution will be invoked later, which ould lead to your formatted not yet being registered when being used. Not to mention that it is confusing as it is deviating from the normal way to configure things.

Comment: I understand. The `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is a difficult API to navigate and doesn't provide an easy way of obtaining the `FormatterRegistry`, and so its difficult for _anyone_ (**not** just you!) to come up with a good way of accessing it. We'll chalk it up to tech debt on the Spring Boot team's plate, but I appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: It isn't difficult at all. You must stop thinging that you must use the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to configure web related things, as that is for security. The `WebMvcConfiguirer` is for MVC related things. You need both if you want to configure security and mvc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this like so:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {

    @Autowired
    public void configureCustomSpringConverters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new MyCustomCoverter());
    }

}
```